# the code "1\u02ff".IndexOf("1") returns -1

Tags: c#, unicode

the C# code `"1\u02ff".IndexOf("1")` returns `-1`

What's special with the unicode char `02ff`?
Why does the code returns `-1`?

Comment: `String.IndexOf()` returns `-1` when there was no matching character or string was found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` and `u02ff` *combine* to form the character `1˿` (image below) which is not the same as `1` in your culture, as [the modifier letter low left arrow (u02ff)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02ff/index.htm) has "modified" the character.

Using `"1\u02ff".IndexOf("1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` will return `0`.

[image]